# How pass function inside directive to another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, using-directives

I have two separated directives. If some condition is evaluated to `true` I have to call second directive inside first.

```
myDirectives.directive('first', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "Views/_first.html",
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      functiontocall: "&",
    }
  }
});
```

In HTML I'm calling directive as following:

```
<first ng-model="model.FirstDTO" 
       functiontocall="someFunctionForAsyncData(val)"></first>
```

Second directive is same, just with different html and passed function. I've omit additional data passed to directive which is not important for my current problem.

Now, I must call second directive inside first, so I've added additional function which is passed to first directive:

```
myDirectives.directive('first', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "Views/_first.html",
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      functiontocall: "&",
      functionforseconddirective: "&"
    }
  }
});
```

How can I, inside my first directive make something like this bellow, pass function that is passed to first directive to another one (it's not working now):

```
<second ng-model="secondModel" 
        secondFn="functionforseconddirective(val)"></second>
```

Just to state that this is special case where these two directive are nested, I have couple of places inside code where I call each of them separately, so I would like solution to this specific situation, but not affecting all normal places in code where both of them are working correctly.

Update: jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/kujg10fL/1/
I would like that click on second button display expected msg

Comment: Where is `functionforseconddirective()` defined? And why do you need to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. you did now show enough information to create a full qualified answer. I think `functionforseconddirective()` is defined in your controller. In that way you don't need to parse this funtion from one directive to another. You need a `trigger` and you need to parse the `value` from on directive to enougher like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxu587p1/)**.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input href="javascript:void(0);" 
         my-directive trigger="trigger" 
         my-value="someValue" />

  <div my-other-directive 
       fn="myTriggerFunction" 
       my-value="someValue" 
       trigger="trigger"></div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.trigger = false;
    $scope.someValue = '';

    $scope.myTriggerFunction = function (value) {
      console.log(value);
    };
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrit: 'A',
      scope: {
        trigger: "=",
        myValue: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('keyup', function () {
            scope.myValue = 'hello world';
            scope.trigger = true;
            scope.$apply();
          });
      }
    }
});

myApp.directive('myOtherDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrit: 'A',
      scope: {
        trigger: "=",
        myValue: "=",
        fn: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('trigger', function (newValue, oldValue) {

            if (newValue) {

              //call controller function
              scope.fn(scope.myValue);

              //unset trigger
              scope.trigger = false;
              scope.$emit();
            }
          });
      }
    }
});
```

---

## Updated answer based on your fiddle

Please check this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4k2ubrv/)**.

#### View

```
<div ng-app="dr" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <test firstfn="someFn"></test>   
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var app = angular.module('dr', []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.someFn = function(msg) {        
        alert(msg.msg);
    }
});
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            firstfn: '='
        },
        template: "<div><button ng-click='firstfn({msg:\"Hello World!\"})'>Click</button><br /> <testinner secondfn='firstfn'></testinner> </div>",
        replace: true,        
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {     
           console.log(scope.firstfn);
        }
    }
});
app.directive('testinner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            secondfn: '='
        },
        template: "<div>second directive<button ng-click='secondfn({msg:\"Hello World from another!\"})'>Click</button></div>",
        replace: true,        
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {             
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: functionforseconddirective() is defined inside BaseController. It's autocomplete function. Mentioned "second directive" is piece of html that show's dropdown list of items from server.
I believe yout solution is working, but it's not exactly what I had in mind.
I would just simply pass function to another directive so when user type something, that another directive calls passed function which calls BaseController function which goes to server.
Honestly, I was hoping for something more simple, without watch and triggers.

Comment: @Error Ok, thanks for you feedback. So how do you want to make the "other directive" executing your passed function without an trigger? This is not possible, you need a listener/watch trigger.

Comment: @Error, please see my updated answer and demo fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/dxu587p1/ this solution works like a charm by using "keypress" bindings. I just had to change the element and the JavaScript event.

Comment: Both directives have template html, and I thought (if possible) that in first directive's html add something like "<second ng-model="secondModel" 
        secondFn="functionforseconddirective(val)"></second>" where functionforseconddirective is passed to first directive . On different htmls, I'm passing different function which is called, but in all situation's so far, I was always using that directive inside html. 
Now, I have situation in which I must use it form directive's temeplate html.

Comment: @Error Join me in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153348/youandmeandyoume

Comment: I've added jsfiddler